# SQL: Get fullname for member and upline member from another table that has the member ids

Tags: mysql, sql

i have 2 tables: tbl_member and tbl_stockist_details.

- tbl_member has member_no and fullname columns.
- tbl_stockist_details has stockist_member_no and upline_member_no colums. Both columns refer to tbl_member.member_no

Now, I have to display stockist member's fullname and his upline's fulln
ame.

I tried:
SELECT * FROM tbl_stockist_details AS st INNER JOIN tbl_member AS m 
WHERE st.stockist_member_no = m.member_no 
OR st.upline_member_no = m.member_no;

But the result was wrong.
Please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should learn proper `join` syntax.  Simple rule:  never use commas in the `from` clause.

You need two joins here:

```
SELECT st.*, m.fullname, mup.fullname as up_fullname
FROM tbl_stockist_details st JOIN
     tbl_member m 
     ON st.stockist_member_no = m.member_no LEFT JOIN
     tbl_member mup
     ON st.upline_member_no = mup.member_no;
```

I used a `left join` in case some members do not have "upline"s.

Comment: u rock!! Exactly as what i needed .. Thanks a lot Gordon.